How to Handle PENDING_PURCHASE State in Adapty.io for Consumable Products?
I'm developing an Android app where users can buy 10 coins, and these coins are added to their profiles stored in Firebase Realtime Database. I’m using Adapty.io to manage in-app purchases, and everything works smoothly with test cards that either always approve or always decline transactions.
The issue arises with slow test cards (the ones that take a few minutes to approve or decline). In such cases, Adapty treats the situation as an error and returns a PENDING_PURCHASE state (reference: Adapty Docs).
Here’s what I’m struggling with:
How can I track when a pending transaction changes to successful?
How can I ensure the user receives the coins they purchased, even if they log out, close the app, or delete their account?
Does Adapty automatically acknowledge these consumable products after they were in a PENDING_PURCHASE state?
